# Testing Exceptions with Nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

Iam using Nunit for my unit tests and I need to unit test a code which throws exception.My code is simillar to this.

```
    public class Myclass
    {
        public int Count
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public void Foo()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Count >3)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

   [TestFixture]
  public class TestMyClass
  {
    [Test]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        var obj = new Myclass();
        obj.Count = 4;
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(obj.Foo);
    }
 }
```

This give a error like this

```
  Expected: <System.Exception>
  But was:  null
```

I found that if I remove the try catch block,unit test passes.But I dont want to change the actual code .Please advise how can I unit test abovementioned code and what is right way of doing it.

Comment: For starters you should not involve message boxes (or any other gui code) in the code you're going to unit test. Also note that your code effectively swallows the exception. It shows it as a message box, but it doesn't rethrow it, so your unit-test will never see it. In short, **you need to change the actual code** because it is not written to be tested. And *no*, the correct way here is not to figure out how to test if a message box was shown. The correct way here is to refactor the code to separate the GUI code from the logic behind it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for advice.I also thought it could be reason but if I comment out the message box line and just have an empty catch block,It still fails and gives same error.I do not understand the reason for that.

Comment: The empty catch block catches the exception but doesn't rethrow it. You're basically saying "I'll take this exception and ignore it". In short, *don't do that*. Add a `throw;` line to the catch block and your unit-test should see the exception, though if that's all that the try/catch does, you should remove it. And again, you should not have GUI code in code that is executed through unit-tests.

Comment: If you need to bump a GUI response out to some other code you should find a different way to do it. Either by returning a result that warrants a message box, but that message box is handled by the GUI code that called your function, or injecting an object into your object/method that can be used to raise the event on, that your GUI code will show a message box in response to.

Comment: Please note that error handling is not a subject to take lightly. If you rethrow the exception *after* showing it to the end-user, it will probably end up being caught by the .NET runtime which will handle it as an uncaught exception, and likely terminate your program. If you want your logic to throw the exception in such a manner that you can test that it is thrown, you should not use the message box in there, and not catch it (at least not swallow it). Then, in the GUI code, you would wrap the call to your method in a try/catch.

Comment: So Is that means if a code has handled exception which does not rethrow itself can not be unit tested?(In case no GUI is involved).

Comment: If you swallow the exception, you can unit-test it, you just can't verify that it threw an exception (because you swallowed it).

Comment: Thats sad,,,In my actual code its a FatalError Custom Exception and its leading to shutdown sequence as mitigation plan in catch block.you mean that I cant unit test that piece(NO GUI involved,just in general).Is this a design issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your method swallows all exceptions, you can't use `Assert.Throws` since no exception is thrown.

If you want to check that an exception is handled in some way you could create an interface:

```
public interface IExceptionHandler
{
    void Handle(Exception ex);
}

public void WinFormsExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public void Handle(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}

public class Myclass
{
    private readonly IExceptionHandler handler;

    public Myclass(IExceptionHandler handler) { this.handler = handler; }
    public Myclass() : this(new WinFormsExceptionHandler()) { }
    public int Count
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Count >3)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.handler.Handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use a mock in your tests, for example using RhinoMocks you could do:

```
[Test]
public void TestFoo()
{
    var handler = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IExceptionHandler>();
    var obj = new Myclass(handler);
    obj.Count = 4;
    obj.Foo();

    handler.AssertWasCalled(h => h.Handle(Arg<Exception>.Is.Anything));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lee,thats exactly I was looking for.I do have a FailureManager which i use in my catch blocks but its static now.I think I can change it and I am also using rhino mocks so your solution is a perfect fit.

Answer (score 3):

[Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24384602/343266) is the correct one, yet I'd like to expand on what you gain by implementing it.

Your design is fine, but **not test friendly**. The problem is twofold:

1. You hide your class dependencies behind static method calls (`MessageBox.Show`)
2. You depend on concrete implementation (`MessageBox`) rather than on abstraction

Fixing second issue will make code testable. You'll have to introduce fake object which you'll verify against in unit test (as Lee suggested). Fixing second issue *correctly* (i.e. by injecting dependency via interface) will also fix first issue.

By introduction of an interface we've done two things:

1. Abstracted use of message box to *general* error handler component -- we no longer depend on purely-gui-related `MessageBox`. Actual error handler still *could be* a message box, but now it just as well could be custom window, system alert or log message. Your class does not need to know what is it, and now it doesn't (we have *separated the concerns*).
2. Introduced dependency of said error handler to tested class -- with this change we have stated loud and clear, *"To function correctly, this class needs error handler"*. This is important information to anyone working with your code later.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy,with this discussion I realized if I already know and handle situations then they are not exceptions they are logical situations which should be part of my main code and only unexpected situations should go to the catch block to initiate any preventive measures.Do you think its correct understanding?

Comment: @TRS: Yep, you are correct. Throwing and catching exception from within same method is usually redundant (you could simply *handle error* when condition is met, `Count > 3`, skipping the exception part). Yet extraction of error handling logic (as Lee suggested) is the way to go, regardless of how error was generated.